# Lua test suites: coroutines test fails under vxWorks 6.9

Tags: lua, vxworks, lua-5.3

I'm trying to integrate Lua 5.3 under vxWorks 6.9. I currently have a problem while running the test suites to check Lua integration with my sistem.
I'm running the tests that are proposed on the lua.org website (http://www.lua.org/tests/).
I've tried many times to understand what exactly fails but it's not so easy: the system reboots itself while executing the "coroutine.lua" file or crashes returning a page fault. Does anyone else tried to do this type of integration?

I've edited luaconf.h with these defines, maybe knowing it may help:

```
#if defined(LUA_USE_VXWORKS)
#define LUA_USE_POSIX
#undef  LUA_USE_DLOPEN
#undef  LUA_USE_READLINE
#define LUA_USE_MKSTEMP
#define LUA_USE_ISATTY
#define LUA_USE_GMTIME_R
#define LUA_32BITS
#define LUA_TMPNAMTEMPLATE "lua_tmpfile_XXXXXX"
#endif
```

Many thanks for your help :)

EDIT: there are some rare cases in which the tests are passed... the system then usually crashes with the same behavior while executing "goto.lua"

EDIT: it fails again even when defining `LUA_COMPAT_5_1` and `LUA_COMPAT_5_2`. The behavior is always the same: a page fault during the execution of the "coroutine.lua" tests or the "goto.lua" tests

Comment: have You  tried defining `LUA_COMPAT_5_2` and/or `LUA_COMPAT_5_1`? Is there anything constructive in Windows logs?

Comment: Technically the test suites are specific to the 5.3 installation, so compatibility should not be an issue (and we don't have any special need that requires such compatibility).
I'm trying it now! :D

Comment: Hi, we are trying to compile lua5.3.4 in vxworks 6.9. Can you provide pointer on apart from makefile, are there any other changes expected? If yes, can you provide us with some basic info.